# Stronger reducing agent

Tags: reduction-potential

Why H$_2$Te is a good reducing agent than H$_2$O .

I think it should be opposite as in water , oxygen has only tendency to release electrons .

Comment: Are you sure about the statement about oxygen's affinity for electrons?

Comment: @airhuff yes it is given in my book

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity):

> "[electronegativity] is a chemical property that describes the
> tendency of an atom to attract electrons (or electron density) towards
> itself.

then according to an electronegativity scale called the *Allen electronegativity*:

> "...neon has the highest electronegativity of all elements, followed
> by fluorine, helium, and oxygen."

By any scale, oxygen is among the most electronegative elements. More to the point, electronegativity decreases as you go down a period, so  $\ce{Te}$ is much less electronegative, much more able to give up its electrons, than oxygen.  Thus, $\ce{H2Te}$ makes a better reducing agent than $\ce{H2O}$.